# Angular 2 Default select option not populating

Tags: angular

I am trying to give my select box the selected option on page load by setting it to a variable like this

```
<select style="border:0;" [(ngModel)]="accountStatuses" >
        option *ngFor="let s of accountStatuses" [ngValue]="s" [selected]="s === user.accountStatus">{{s}}</option>
</select>
```

The select box has its optioned, but on page load, none are selected.

Here is the relevant bits of typescript.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'user-detail',
    templateUrl: './user-detail.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./user-detail.component.css']
})

export class UserDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    user: User;
    userRoles: UserRole[] = [];

    roleAmountStatusMessage = 'Show More..'
    roleAmountStatus = false;
    rolesSice1 = 1;
    rolesSice2 = 10;

    pageRequests: PageRequest[] = [];

    accountStatuses = ['Archived', 'Disabled', 'Enabled', 'Locked'];

    constructor(private userService: UserService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private roleService: RoleService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        let userId = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.userService.getUser(userId).then(user => this.user = user);
        this.userService.getUserLast25PageRequests(userId).then(pageRequest => this.pageRequests = pageRequest);
        this.roleService.getRolesByUserId(userId).then(userRoles => this.userRoles = userRoles);
    }
```

Comment: Can we see the actual typescript? It sounds like you need to initialize it in an ngOnInit

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I can't find a working plunkr with material beta 12 that's working so I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Joris I've added it to the post

Comment: @Lakston check out the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this example:

```
accountStatus: AccountStatus;
accountStatuses: AccountStatus[];

<select [(ngModel)]="accountStatus" >
        <option *ngFor="let s of accountStatuses" [ngValue]="s">{{s}}</option>
</select>
```

Let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 0):

I think you should introduce a new field like

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedAccountStatuses"
```

instead of

```
[(ngModel)]="accountStatuses"
```

```
class MyComponent {
  selectedAccountStatus:string;

   ngOnInit() {
     ... 
     this.selectedAccountStatus = this.accountstatuses[0];
   }
```

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedAccountStatuses"
```

and remove

```
[selected]="s === user.accountStatus"
```